# How to rename /dev/sdax(partitions) in Linux

Tags: mount, partition, rename, fstab

I made a partition like `/part` on my machine with some important data...

But I can't stand the name of it...

I want a clear solution to resolve it and change the name of it to for example `/test`...

As you see this is my `/etc/fstab` information:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a21a99c4-e5b4-4197-ac5e-80d0fab1f30c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=2e37d833-ca34-4fa7-a5d8-a4423a5af9bc /home           ext4    defaults          0       2
# /part was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5 /part           ext4    defaults          0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=485e9f78-4dce-4404-af4e-f43985525264 none            swap    sw                0       0
```

The point is: My information are important and I scare to manipulate it without being sure...
I want a safe solution...

How is it possible?

Comment: to watching which dev is used, apply: `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/[the-given-uuid] -l`

Comment: @Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh thank you but I didn't understand the strange `the-given-uuid` part

Comment: for example for /part , your should use : `ls -l  /dev/disk/by-uuid/47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5`

Comment: I know///but I didn't get such things(`47e6e0b1-0e57-4184-a378-375b9ce315c5`).It refers to for example sda1, I think this is uuid, Isn't it?

Comment: You wrote scare, i introduce it because i think you have problem with uuid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Unmount the partition:

  ```
  # umount /part
  ```
- Rename the directory after making sure it's not mounted:

  ```
  # mountpoint /part &>/dev/null || mv /part /best_name_ever
  ```
- Edit `/etc/fstab` to replace `/part` with `/best_name_ever`
- Remount the partition:

  ```
  mount /best_name_ever
  ```

The `#` is of course meant to represent your `root` prompt, not actual input to be typed in.

**To test the safety of this solution or any other one on dummy data**

The following instructions are (in part) stolen from [Virtual Filesystem: Building A Linux Filesystem From An Ordinary File](http://freecode.com/articles/virtual-filesystem-building-a-linux-filesystem-from-an-ordinary-file).

- Create an ordinary file with a size of 20 MB (for example):

  ```
  $ dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy_fs bs=1k count=20480 # 20480 = 20 * 1024
  ```
- Create an `ext4` filesystem on your file:

  ```
  $ /sbin/mkfs -t ext4 dummy_fs       
  mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
  dummy_fs is not a block special device.
  Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
  ... # Output of mkfs
  ```
- Mount the filesystem image, create some dummy data on it and test the solution:

  ```
  # mkdir /tmp/testmount
  # mount -o loop dummy_fs /tmp/testmount
  # touch /tmp/testmount/{blah,bleh} # Create dummy data
  # ls /tmp/testmount
  blah bleh lost+found
  # umount /tmp/testmount
  # mountpoint /tmp/testmount &>/dev/null || mv /tmp/testmount /tmp/sexy_name
  # mount -o loop dummy_fs /tmp/sexy_name
  # ls /tmp/sexy_name # to ensure your data is intact:
  blah bleh lost+found
  ```

Comment: pardon, I didn't get the last paragraph :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC I will write a more detailed explanation in a bit.

Comment: @MortezaLSC Please see if this explanation helps.

Comment: @MortezaLSC You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :)